# passing data using hyperlink in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to pass the path of an image ['guest'] from one page to another using a link. (I'm storing URLs of images in database)
Can't seem to get the image to display, which is a bigger image of 'url'. I'm doing it this way so that I can have a larger image displayed in the target page (does_this_work.php) plus adding some other bits on the page too.

I'm still learning and can;t seem to see what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated,

```
<?php 

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name=""; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password)or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("cannot select DB");


$photo=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `images` ORDER BY (ID = 11) DESC, RAND() LIMIT 7");

while($get_photo=mysql_fetch_array($photo)){ ?>

<div style="width:300px;">


<a href="does_this_work.php?big_image=$get_photo['guest']>" target=""><img src="<?     
echo $get_photo['url']; ?>" title="">


 </div>

 <? } ?>
```

I then use the following code to try and display the array data in the target file

```
<?php

echo "this is the page where you get a larger picture of image on previous page, plus     
further info";

$big_image = $_GET['guest'];

echo $big_image;

?>
```

Comment: while there are many other things wrong with this: $_GET['big_image'] not $_GET['guest']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. First of all, this is how you use $_GET and $_POST:

ex. site.php?argument=value

To retrieve the value of argument, you need this code in site.php:

```
//The variable must not necessarily be $value
$value = $_GET['argument'];
//Alt.
$value = $_POST['argument'];
```

Secondly (like the other answers tell you) you are missing a php-tag here:

```
<a href="does_this_work.php?big_image=$get_photo['guest']>" target=""><img src="<? echo $get_photo['url']; ?>" title="">
```

Instead it should be:

```
<a href="does_this_work.php?big_image=<?php echo $get_photo['guest']; ?>" target=""><img src="<?php echo $get_photo['url']; ?>" title="">
```

Now, in order to make that compatible with your second code, you need to change the argument sent to guest like this:

```
<a href="does_this_work.php?guest=<?php echo $get_photo['guest']; ?>" target=""><img src="<?php echo $get_photo['url']; ?>" title="">
```

OR change the $_GET['guest']; to $_GET['big_image'];

I think I got it all right..

Comment: thanks for that. Have made changes but still not getting the image displayed on does_this_work.php. Have tried putting

Comment: Does $big_image; include the <img>-tag? If not, have you added it to the echo? (Talking about your second script now.)

Comment: thanks for that. Can't tell you how long I've been on that for!cheers

Comment: Yeah, adding the image tag displayed the image. Cheers

Comment: Hehe, no problems. Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an opening tag in here (And a closing semi colon, but that's not as problematic here):

```
<a href="does_this_work.php?big_image=$get_photo['guest'] ?>"
```

Change to:

```
<a href="does_this_work.php?big_image=<?= $get_photo['guest']; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="does_this_work.php?big_image=$get_photo['guest'] ?>" target=""><img src="<?     
echo $get_photo['url']; ?>" title="">
```

You are missing your php starting tags. This should read:

```
<a href="does_this_work.php?big_image=<? $get_photo['guest'] ?>" target=""><img src="<?     
echo $get_photo['url']; ?>" title="">
```

Comment: `<? $get_photo['guest'] ?>`,  what do you expect that to 'do'?

Comment: <?= Oops. Yeah that usually helps.

Comment: Cheers for your help on that.